# calling Xib upon xib not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using one Main Xib (`UIViewController`) on its view calling  another xib (named as selectionViewController) (`which contains some UIButtons which is required to call another xib`)

button action conatins this code

```
- (IBAction)xibCaller:(UIButton *)sender {
formsViewController  *obj_Editor =[[formsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"formsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_Editor animated:YES];

  if (obj_Editor.isViewLoaded && obj_Editor.view.window) {
    NSLog(@"XIB Called");
}
```

}

When the button is clicked its not redirected to formViewContoller why ??
It only works when I add this line after navigation

```
 [self.view addSubview:obj_Editor.view];
```

this way loads formsViewController views upon this selectionView which I don't want

Can someone help me

Comment: Are you working storyboard or normal XIBs

Comment: formsViewController  *obj_Editor =[[formsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"formsViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: already using same way

Comment: And check your outlet setting this controller between File's Owner and view.

Comment: checked it's correct

Comment: Do you have a valid/non null navigation controller?

Comment: yes , for more testing i made two button one on Main xib which worked with old code flawless , second button on second xib (this xib is loading upon main xib ) this button still unable to navigate

Comment: What did you write the coding in viewDidLoad of formsViewController?